# "action_page.php" in form error leads to Error 404

Tags: html, forms, button, hyperlink, demo

I want to create a form in HTML and I am leading it to the demo page, "action_page.php". When I press "Submit" it shows Error 404.

I tried changing the attribute up and down but it is still saying Error 404. Is this the right demo link? I double-checked. Can someone show how to fix this and some steps on what to do?

Here is the code I have put to make it clear to you:

```html
<form action="action_page.php"
<input type="submit" value="Submit Survey"
</form>
```

In conclusion, how can I make the demo link "action_page.php" work? (HTML Answer)

Comment: You did not closed form tag and forget to add a method to your form like method="post"

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: in html when you open tags you need to close them <form action="" method=""> ... </form>

Comment: you have the same thing in input

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Survey">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like that:

```
<form action="Page.php" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Survey" name='getlol'>
</form>
<?php
$_get['getlol'];
echo "You submitted the survey!";
?>
```

Comment: in this case not necessarily because `GET` is the default value but if you want to send a `POST` request you have to put it.
like that --->  `method="POST"`

Comment: send data from client to server. 

see this example ---> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp